# Strip the tags of a page and get an array or a separated list of page numbers returned

Tags: php, html, curl, strip-tags

I'm trying to strip the tags of this page down to the point that I can get a list of the page numbers. So I can figure out what the highest page number is for my curl program to continue to crawl the page's. Right now I'm able to strip the tags down to a point where a get a the numbers but I can't figure out how to separate each number so I can see what the highest page number is.

The current return value I receive is

> 12

Here is my code:

```
<?php
// Defining the basic pruning function
function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
    $data = stristr($data, $start); // Stripping all data from before $start
    $data = substr($data, strlen($start));  // Stripping $start
    $stop = stripos($data, $end);   // Getting the position of the $end of the data to scrape
    $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);    // Stripping all data from after and including the $end of the data to scrape
    return $data;   // Returning the scraped data from the function
}

ob_start();
?>
<span class="current">1</span><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$phCenterColumn$motoSearchResults$gvCatalog$ctl01$ctl03','')">2</a><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$phCenterColumn$motoSearchResults$gvCatalog$ctl01$ctl04','')">

<?php
$variable = ob_get_clean();

$startend5 = Array('">' => '</a>');

foreach($startend5 as $o => $p){
   $data = scrape_between($variable, $o, $p);
}
$data = strip_tags($data);
echo $data;
?>
```

FYI the ob_start(); and the ob_get_clean(); are only for the example didn't want to make the code base any longer than necessary including all of the curl commands.

Comment: could you use `$startend5 = Array('">' => '</span>')` to get the number `1` and then `$startend6 = Array('">' => '</a>')` to get the number `2`?

Comment: Problem there would be there typically are going to be more then 2 pages the example code I kind of cropped. Typically the tags around page 2 would be repeated several times. Didn't want my post code to be to long.

Comment: Also I can't modify my Scrape_between function because I use it during my Curl Crawl of the website several times and it works perfectly on everything else except for this due to the way the page was coded with no spaces and not returns.

Comment: Ok so I had an idea about how to fix this. This works for the first 9 pages but if there are more then 9 pages I'm not sure what to do.
    if(count($data) <= 9){
     $new_data = str_split($data, 1);
     }

Answer (score 0):

may I suggest the [PHP DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library. You can access these values like so:

```
<?php
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';
    $html = str_get_html("<span class=\"current\">1</span><a href=\"javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00\$phCenterColumn\$motoSearchResults\$gvCatalog\$ctl01\$ctl03','')\">2</a><a href=\"javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00\$phCenterColumn\$motoSearchResults\$gvCatalog\$ctl01\$ctl04','')\">");

    $currentPage = $html->find('span.current');
    foreach($currentPage as $page)
    {
        echo 'current page: ' . $page->plaintext . '<br />';
    }

    $otherPages = $html->find('a');
    echo 'other pages: ';
    foreach($otherPages as $otherPage)
    {
        echo $otherPage->plaintext . ' ';
    }
?>
```

this gave me:

```
current page: 1
other pages: 2
```